# How to create a temporary query in VSTS ?? createquery() only creates ,getquery() gives error?

Tags: typescript, azure-devops

```
let query = "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] 
            From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' 
            order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc";

client.getQuery("DMPLM_TP1", query).then ((wi) => {}, (query) => {});
```

> error : 
>   TF401243: The query Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc does not exist, or you do not have permission to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can’t create a temporary query, but you can retrieve work items through [queryByWiql](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_1#method_queryByWiql) function with querystring.

```
IPromise<Contracts.WorkItemQueryResult> queryByWiql(wiql, project, team)
```

There is the sample: [WorkItemSearch.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/ui-fabric-react/scripts/WorkItemSearch.ts)